# Disable an option(s) in a dropdown Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to disable 1(or 2) dropdown option from a dropdown menu in Unity.
[image]
The dropdown menu should not be **repopulated**.

There should not be any deletion/deactivated options from the dropdown menu

Anyone have any idea how to do this. ?

Comment: You can use [interactable](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable-interactable.html)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the interactable will just disable the dropdown to be not clickable... however I still want to be able to select the option A, C, E

Comment: Did you try <https://answers.unity.com/questions/1426927/disable-a-dropdown-option.html>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55298541/7111561) but a slightly different approach.

The other answer uses a hardcoded `toggle.name == "Item 1: Option B"` to compare the buttons. I'd rather use a central and index-based system:

Put this component on the `DropDown`

```cs
[RequireComponent(typeof(Dropdown))]
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
public class DropDownController : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    [Tooltip("Indexes that should be ignored. Indexes are 0 based.")]
    public List<int> indexesToDisable = new List<int>();

    private Dropdown _dropdown;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _dropdown = GetComponent<Dropdown>();
    }

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        var dropDownList = GetComponentInChildren<Canvas>();
        if (!dropDownList) return;

        // If the dropdown was opened find the options toggles
        var toogles = dropDownList.GetComponentsInChildren<Toggle>(true);

        // the first item will always be a template item from the dropdown we have to ignore
        // so we start at one and all options indexes have to be 1 based
        for (var i = 1; i < toogles.Length; i++)
        {
            // disable buttons if their 0-based index is in indexesToDisable
            // the first item will always be a template item from the dropdown
            // so in order to still have 0 based indexes for the options here we use i-1
            toogles[i].interactable = !indexesToDisable.Contains(i - 1);
        }
    }

    // Anytime change a value by index
    public void EnableOption(int index, bool enable)
    {
        if (index < 1 || index > _dropdown.options.Count)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Index out of range -> ignored!", this);
            return;
        }

        if (enable)
        {
            // remove index from disabled list
            if (indexesToDisable.Contains(index)) indexesToDisable.Remove(index);
        }
        else
        {
            // add index to disabled list
            if (!indexesToDisable.Contains(index)) indexesToDisable.Add(index);
        }

        var dropDownList = GetComponentInChildren<Canvas>();

        // If this returns null than the Dropdown was closed
        if (!dropDownList) return;

        // If the dropdown was opened find the options toggles
        var toogles = dropDownList.GetComponentsInChildren<Toggle>(true);
        toogles[index].interactable = enable;
    }

    // Anytime change a value by string label
    public void EnableOption(string label, bool enable)
    {
        var index = _dropdown.options.FindIndex(o => string.Equals(o.text, label));

        // We need a 1-based index
        EnableOption(index + 1, enable);
    }
}
```

Configure in the Inspector

[image]

or via scripts e.g.

```
dropDownReference.GetComponent<DropDownController>().EnableOption("Option B", false);
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thankkkk youuu very muccch for your detailed answer..!! 
Its working awesomelyy ...! ヽ(・∀・)ﾉ

Comment: This is a wise move, but I wish there was a way to do this without having to create a wrapper component

Comment: Perfect Solution :)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using the `Toggle` component from DropDown->Template->ViewPort->Content->Item.

This script is creating items every time `DropDown` menu is selected. You can just access `Toogle` and disable interactable field like this:

```c#
void Start () 
{
    //This script should be attached to Item
    Toggle toggle = gameObject.GetComponent<Toggle>();
    Debug.Log(toggle);
    if (toggle != null && toggle.name == "Item 1: Option B")
    {
        toggle.interactable = false;
    }
}
```

You can also see a DropDown list is created every time arrow on DrowDown is clicked and destroyed when menu is closed.

Comment: Niceee., it workkss..!! Thank you very much for youurrr help again...^_^