# Unity3D - How to change color for ItemLabel in DropDown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text, dropdown

I am using a DropDown element in Unity,
in my code I disable some choices if the requirements are not met with:

```
  var toogles = dropDownList.GetComponentsInChildren<Toggle>(true);
  toogles[index].interactable = enable;
```

I also want to change the color of the ItemLabel text for the disabled toggles,
I tried:

```
       var mylabel = dropDownList.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>(true);
       mylabel[index].color = Color.red;
```

but doesn´t work, I somehow need to store that ItemLabel in a variable that is created under Dropdown/Template/Item/ItemLabel

I tried to create a `public Text` where I drag & dropped the ItemLabel that is created under template, but since its not the exact Text that gets created, its only a template, it didnt work.

Anybody knows how to access that ItemLabel of the DropDown?

EDIT:

I got this far:

```
    if(toogles[i].interactable == false)
        {
            _dropdown.itemText.color = Color.red;
        }
```

but dont know how to add the indexes, so only some of the items will be Red

Comment: I think similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297626/disable-an-options-in-a-dropdown-unity) you could access the dynamically generated toggle's afterwards and change their text color.

Comment: this is where I took the code from, the Toggle is child of the DropDown, but the Item Label is part of the Template, dont know how to access it

Comment: Once you have the according toggle you can `GetComponentInChildren<Text>(true)` on it

Comment: `var toogles = dropDownList.GetComponentsInChildren<Toggle>(true);
        toogles[index].interactable = enable;
        var mylabel = toogles[index].GetComponentInChildren<Text>(true);
        mylabel.color = Color.red;`

doesnt seem to work, but I did exactly as you said. The interactable part works, but the label doesnt get colored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find and iterate through the itemLabels with this code:

```
 var myLabels = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ItemLabel");
        var objectCount = myLabels.Length;
        Debug.Log("Object count:" + objectCount);
        Text[] myItemLabels = new Text[6];
        int k = 0;
        foreach (var obj in myLabels)
        {
          myItemLabels[k] = obj.GetComponent<Text>();
          k++;
        }
```